# Закрыть выпадающее меню при нажатии вне его

Tags: javascript, click, dropdown

Сейчас меню отрывается при нажатии на поле ввода и закрывается при нажатии на соседнее поле.
Хотелось бы, чтобы оно закрывалось и при нажатии вне его.
`Event.stopPropagation()` не подходит.

```js
function showFilterList() {
  const title = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__category-title--mobile')
  let list = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__general-content-container')
  if (title && list) {
    title.forEach((e) => {
      e.addEventListener('click', function(c) {
        let path = c.currentTarget.dataset.path;
        list.forEach((b) => {
          b.classList.remove('catalog__general-content-container--active')
        })
        document.querySelector(`[data-target="${path}"]`).classList.add('catalog__general-content-container--active')
      })
    })
  }
}


showFilterList();
```

```html
<div class="catalog__sale-container catalog__general-list">
  <h4 class="catalog__sale-title catalog__category-title--mobile title-reset" data-path="sale">Скидка</h4>
  <div class="catalog__sale-list-container catalog__general-content-container" data-target="sale">
    <ul class="catalog__sale list-reset">
      <li class="catalog__sale-items">
        <label class="catalog__sale-label checkbox-label" for="checkbox_18">
          <input type="checkbox" class="catalog__sale-checkbox checkbox-label__input" id="checkbox_18"/>
          <span class="catalog__span-accept checkbox-label__span">Более 5 000</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="catalog__sale-items">
        <label class="catalog__sale-label checkbox-label" for="checkbox_19">
          <input type="checkbox" class="catalog__sale-checkbox checkbox-label__input" id="checkbox_19"/>
          <span class="catalog__span-accept checkbox-label__span">Менее 5 000</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="catalog__sale-items">
        <label class="catalog__sale-label checkbox-label" for="checkbox_20">
          <input type="checkbox" class="catalog__sale-checkbox checkbox-label__input" id="checkbox_20"/>
          <span class="catalog__span-accept checkbox-label__span">Без скидки</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [не смотрели ведь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E)

Comment: Мне кажется вы прикрепили неполноценный код.

Comment: целый день уже смотрю, у меня даже есть код работающий, но он не подходит для этого случая, так тут несколько селектов.

Comment: Для начала, отмечайте участников знаком "@" чтобы они увидели ваш ответ, если вы не пишите под их же вопросом/ответом․ Вот так - @Ольга.

Comment: А потом я у вас вижу код, который объявлен, но не использован. А если его удалить, то останется только HTML. Так что не могу запустить ваш пример, чтобы разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: Для закрытия "вне" - нужно знать пару деталей... 1 - как найти родительский контейнер. 2 - что нужно делать чтобы элемент "закрылся". Далее на весь документ вешаем обработчик события `click`. Проверяем принадлежит ли он нашему контейнеру... Если принадлежит - запускаем функцию "закрытия". По твоим кускам не понятно на 100% как определить контейнер и что нужно делать для закрытия.

Comment: @ksa,  разобралась. добавила вот это в нужном месте

``` window.addEventListener('click', (a) => {
                console.log('click')
                const target = a.target 
                if (!target.closest('.catalog__category-title--mobile') && !target.closest('.catalog__general-content-container')) { 
                  b.classList.remove('catalog__general-content-container--active') 
                }
              }```

Comment: Вот и молодец что разобралась. ;)